# How to unlock sa user in SQL Server 2012 if Windows Authentication doesn't work?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am logged in as an admin on the computer. For some reason I can't log into SQL Server 2012 which is running on the same machine. The SA user is locked out. SQL Server was installed when I was logged in into my company's domain. I am not logged into the domain when I try to log in to sql server. I don't know if this matters st all.

However I expect to log using Windows authentication if I am in the administrator group?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to log in using the same user that you installed SQL Server with. Beginning with SQL 08, the administrators group, by default no longer has access. You have to give access to the administrators group explicitly.